# I am unable to parse the json array using angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is the JSON which I am getting and I am storing that in variable using,

JS:-

```
$scope.shopData = resp.data.shopVal;
```

On the JSP page its not working in ng-repeat tag.

JSON:-

```
{
    "subCategoryNames": null,
    "subCategorymMap": {},
    "shopVal": [
        {
            "shopAdrs": "tex10",
            "shopSrvc": "tex12",
            "shopName": "tex13",
            "shopWbst": "tex14"
        },
        {
            "shopAdrs": "tex15",
            "shopSrvc": "tex16",
            "shopName": "tex16",
            "shopWbst": "tex17"
        },
        {
            "shopAdrs": "tex18",
            "shopSrvc": "tex19",
            "shopName": "tex20",
            "shopWbst": "tex21"
        }
    ],
    "ownerVal": {
        "ownrNumbr": "1111111111",
        "ownrFName": "ABCD",
        "ownrLName": "EFGH",
        "ownrEmail": "ABXD305@GMAIL.COM"
    }
}
```

JSP:-

```
<div data-ng-repeat="shop in shopDta">
<a>
{{shopDta.shopName}}<br>
Address: {{shopDta.shopAdrs}}<br>
Services: {{shopDta.shopSrvc}}<br>
Website: {{shopDta.shopWbst}}<br><br>
</a>
</div>
```

Note that $scope.shopData is correctly getting value as per JSON. Please help

Comment: As an output, only the hardcoded strings are getting printed. please help.

Comment: you can't iterate objects through ng-repeat, go for array and then iterate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, you are trying to iterate an Object using ng-repeat which is not possible, you need to get the array and put it inside ng-repeat, i have done some changes, hope this works out for you.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="shop in shopData.shopVal">
<a>
{{shop.shopName}}<br>
Address: {{shop.shopAdrs}}<br>
Services: {{shop.shopSrvc}}<br>
Website: {{sho[.shopWbst}}<br><br>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to help mate

Answer (score 0):

try this, you are trying to iterate an Object using ng-repeat which is not possible, you need to get the array and put it inside ng-repeat, i have done some changes, hope this works out for you.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="shop in shopData">
  <a>
    {{shop.shopName}}<br>
    Address: {{shop.shopAdrs}}<br>
    Services: {{shop.shopSrvc}}<br>
    Website: {{shop.shopWbst}}<br><br>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

`<div data-ng-repeat="shop in shopData">
<a>
{{shop.shopName}}<br>
Address: {{shop.shopAdrs}}<br>
Services: {{shop.shopSrvc}}<br>
Website: {{shop.shopWbst}}<br><br>
</a>
</div>`

Comment: Kepp posting your  problems :) Happy coding :D